# Returning list of repeating tags in XML structure in java

Tags: java, xml

I am writing RESTful webservice.

Server: Glassfish 4.0
IDE: Eclipse

I am expecting XML like this i.e  tag shall repeat for all the items in the order as there *could be multiple items in an order*.

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Items>
   <Item>A</Item>
   <Item>B</Item>
   <Item>C</Item>
    </Items>
   <User>Simran</User>
   <Total_amount>1100</Total_amount>
  </Order>
  <Order>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <Items>
   <Item>A</Item>
   <Item>B</Item>
   <Item>D</Item>
   </Items>
   <User>Simran</User>
   <Total_amount>1300</Total_amount>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

**What I get with my current code: (No  tag)**

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <User>Simran</User>
   <Total_amount>1100</Total_amount>
  </Order>
  <Order>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <User>Simran</User>
   <Total_amount>1300</Total_amount>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

URL:http://localhost:8080/GigstartServices/GET/Users/1/Orders

I do not get any exceptions/errors/or deployment problems either.
Code in java:

**Orders.java** looks like this :

```
 package com.dto;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Orders {

        private int id;
        private ArrayList<Integer> items;
        private int userId;
        private int totalAmount;

    public Orders(){

        }
    private ArrayList<Integer> Items;
        public Orders(int id,ArrayList<Integer> items, int userId , int totalAmount){
            Items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            this.id = id;
            this.Items = items;
            this.userId = userId;
            this.totalAmount = totalAmount;

        }
        /**
         * @return the Id
         */
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        /**
         * set Id
         */
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        /**
         * @return the ItemId
         */
        @XmlElementWrapper(name="Items")
        @XmlElement(name="Item")
        public ArrayList<Integer> getItemId() {
            return Items;
        }
        /**
         * @set name
         */
        public void setItem(ArrayList<Integer> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }
        /**
         * @return price
         */
        public int getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }
        /**
         * set price
         */
        public void setUserId(int userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public int getTotalAmount(){
            return totalAmount;
        }

        public void setTotalAmount(int totalAmount){
            this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
        }
    }
```

**OrderResource.java**

```
package com.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.dto.Orders;

public class OrderResource {
int total;
    public ArrayList<Orders> GetOrders(Connection connection, int id) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Orders> feedData = new ArrayList<Orders>();
        ArrayList<Integer> itemsId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT o.id, o.userId FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id join dbo.Users u on o.UserId = u.Id where o.UserId = ?");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Orders o = new Orders();
                o.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT ItemId,price FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id where o.UserId= ?");
                ps.setInt(1, id);
                ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs2.next()){
                itemsId.add(rs2.getInt("ItemId"));
                total = total + rs2.getInt("price");
                }
                o.setItem(itemsId);
                o.setUserId(rs.getInt("userId"));
                o.setTotalAmount(total);
                feedData.add(o);
            }
            return feedData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

**OrderService.java**

```
package com.webService;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.dao.Database;
import com.dao.OrderResource;
import com.dao.Resources;
import com.dto.Items;
import com.dto.Orders;
@Path("/")  
public class OrderService {
OrderService(){

}
    ArrayList<Orders> u = null;
    Database database= new Database();

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        public ArrayList<Orders> getOrders(@PathParam("userid") int userid) throws Exception
        {
            Connection connection = database.GetConnection();
            OrderResource ur= new OrderResource();
            u=ur.GetOrders(connection, userid);
         return u;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Becuase you do not set your `Items` but you set `items`

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Items")
    @XmlElement(name="Item")
    public ArrayList<Integer> getItemId() {
        return **Items**;
    }
    /**
     * @set name
     */
    public void setItem(ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        **this.items** = items;
    }
```

Comment: @sgpatil: That did not help.The results did not change